# You have an error in your SQL syntax...near 'float) / CAST(rating_count AS float)) as average_rating from document'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Following is the query

```
select id, IF(rating_count = 0, null, CAST(rating_sum AS float) / CAST(rating_count AS float)) as average_rating 
from document d left join document_aggregate_rating using (id) where id in (123);
```

and error I am getting

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'float) / CAST(rating_count AS float)) as average_rating from document' at line 1
```

I can't figure out why is it giving syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to do the cast.  The division produces a decimal, even when both arguments are integers.  Also, `nullif()` is shorter (and more standard) than `if()`:

```
select id, rating_sum / nullif(rating_count, 0) as average_rating 
from document d left join
     document_aggregate_rating dar
     using (id)
where id = 123;
```

Finally, it is unclear where the columns are coming from.  But, if both come from `document_aggregate_rating`, you can phrase the query without a join:

```
select 123 as id, max(rating_sum) / nullif(max(rating_count), 0) as average_rating 
from document_aggregate_rating dar
where id in (123);
```

The aggregation guarantees that one row is returned, even when there are no matches.

Comment: `nullif` is elegant, thanks. and looks like I will have to handle `DECIMAL` to `FLOAT` conversion in code

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
select id, IF(rating_count = 0, null, 
CAST(rating_sum AS DECIMAL(10,6)) / CAST(rating_count AS DECIMAL(10,6))) as average_rating 
from document d left join document_aggregate_rating 
using (id) where id in (123);
```

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) says:

> The type for the result can be one of the following values:
>
> - BINARY[(N)]
> - CHAR[(N)]
> - DATE
> - DATETIME
> - DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
> - SIGNED [INTEGER]
> - TIME
> - UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

Comment: but I want float not decimal

Comment: @shreyas:- Any specific reason for that? Also to note that Decimal has got a higher precision when compared to FLOAT or DOUBLE.

Comment: @shreyas:- Also the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) clearly says that you need to make it as Decimal instead of Float when using CAST.

Comment: agreed decimal has higher precision but I want float because when I get value in python DECIMAL type is not native and can't be directly serialized in json

Comment: so this means I can't cast to float?

Comment: @shreyas:- Using CAST in MySQL, the answer is **NO**

Comment: is this legit way `rating_sum * 1.0 / rating_count` to get float?

Comment: @shreyas:- You can use the answer given by Gordon. You can simply use  `rating_sum / nullif(rating_count, 0)` Also your way is fine i.e, `rating_sum * 1.0 / rating_count`

Comment: :- although your answer is useful I will select Gordon's answer since it is more elegant and explains auto casting